# Configure HTML Purifier to allow href with file:// protocol

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using HTMLPurifier to filter the HTML coming in from TinyMCE. I'm trying to configure it so that a user is able to add `file://F:\*` as `href` for links.

*Note: `F` could be any other letter, it's just to illustrate that two `:` need to be present in the URL, which I assume also requires configuration.*

### Current behavior

HTMLPurifier removes the `href` attribute if the URI protocol is not `http|https`.

### Expected behavior

Either allow only `http|https|file` or allow all protocols.

### What I have already tried

I have added this configuration, but with the use of this option, the entire list of allowed attributes must be defined, which is not optimal so I'm rather looking for another option that does not require to define the entire attributes list.

```
$config->set("HTML.AllowedAttributes", "a.href");
```

There is also a link to the HTMLPurifier forum that shows up on Google but the forum seems to be down...

Thanks.

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.AllowedSchemes - what happens if you add `file => true` to this configuration?

Comment: @pinkgothic It does work, thanks, But now the URI is removed after the second `:`. E.g.: `file://P:\Folder\OtherFolder\File.extension` becomes `file://P`. I assume this is because it does lot like having two `:` in the URL. Do you know how this can be configured ?

Comment: Sorry for the extreme delay! I hope you figured something out by now, on your own; I actually don't think there's an easy configuration switch for this? You may have to dig into code customisation.

Answer (score 0):

In library/AttrDef/URI

just add a new file with the name you want
eg file.php
and extend the abstract HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI

eg

```
class HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI_file extends HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI
```

In there you can validate the incoming $uri with your own logic, return only true if it succeeds and if it doesnt just let it validate with the parent function

then you can add your new AttrDefinition with

```
$def = config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'href', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_URI_file());
```